# jquery: find not working w.r.t the html response from a ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get html web page using ajax and then try to find a specific div

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
 console.log($(data).find("div#container").html());
});
```

While debugging I see `$(data)` in console as

```
>> $(data)
Object { 0: #text, 1: title, 2: #text, 3: link, 4: #text, 5: link, 6: #text, 7: meta, 8: #text, 9: meta, … }
```

If i expand I can see

[image]

But when I check

```
>> $(data).find("div#container")
Object { length: 0, prevObject: {…}, context: undefined, selector: "div#container" }
```

How can I get that element from `$(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of the HTML output in the image, there is no root element to `find()` from. As such, use `filter()` instead:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
  console.log($(data).filter("#container").html());
});
```

Comment: Great answer. thanks

Comment: what is the connection with root

Comment: No problem, glad to help. By 'root' I mean a containing element in the HTML. What element that is depends on the context.